# Pass "volume-driver" option to kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is it possible to pass the "--volume-driver" with in kubernetes' yml file?

Ex. Using Docker I can perform the following

docker run --volume-driver rbd -v image:/mountpoint ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5388 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/9870/files might be related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes does support several volume types, including rbd, as you mention in your example. When you create a pod, you can specify what volumes and their types you want in the yaml file.  Documentation on volumes is here: http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/volumes.html#rbd

Kubernetes uses its own volume system that is different from Docker's: Kubenetes supports some types of volumes that Docker doesn't and vice versa.

Comment: Agree on the kubernetes' own rbd support but unfortunately from what I read it won't play nice with CoreOS as the worker node. The reason is  CoreOS doesn't have the ceph libraries to fully support it.

Comment: We do not yet have integration with Dockers (relatively new) volume plugins.